# {14, 16, 18} to {16, 16, 16} by -1 from any 2 columns and adding 2 to the 3rd column.

Tags: logic, problem-solving

You own a bunch of cats. These cats have special properties. Firstly, the cats come in yellow, purple and green. Secondly, if two differently coloured cats spend time together, they both change into the third colour cat.  You have 14 blue cats, 16 red cats and 18 green cats. Is it possible to get the same number of cats for each colour?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is usually no.  The usual approach is to find a quantity that is invariant under the transformations, then to show that the quantity is different in the start state and the end state.

Hint:  what happens to the vector of cat numbers $\bmod 3$ at each meeting?

Comment: Observing in a few repetitions is indicative but not a proof.  A proof would start with $(2,1,0)$, consider each of the three possible meetings, and show each one results in $(2,1,0)$ in some order.  In fact it always results in $(1,0,2)$, then $(0,2,1)$ and back to $(2,1,0)$.  You could then conclude that no set of meetings could get you to $(1,1,1)$.